# How to retrieve DOM from a fully loaded page with the Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I am working on creating a feature to make a site with paginated content, similar to an Amazon product page, compatible with infinite scrolling using the Fetch API. According to Amazon's specifications, you can navigate through pages by changing the value of the 'page' URL parameter to 2, 3, 4, and so on. I intend to use this mechanism to fetch the product information for the next page using the Fetch API without having to click. Additionally, I would like to handle this page's information as a Document Object Model (DOM).

As a result of my initial attempts, I created the following code and executed it from the Console in the developer tools:

```
fetch('https://www.amazon.com/s?k=python&page=3')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html'))
    .then(document => {
        console.log(document)
  });
```

However, when I examine the information returned in the console, I cannot find the expected product information within the DOM. It appears that the initial HTML loaded does not contain the product information and that this information is loaded dynamically afterward.

How to fetch dynamically loaded HTML information using the Fetch API?

I executed the above code.

Comment: I think Javascript only is not enough to fetch documents dynamically. You can move forward to try the web scrapper method with some library like [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), Playwright, or Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when I examine the information returned in the console, I cannot find the expected product information within the DOM.

You haven't done anything to add it to the DOM. You've parsed it into a document, but then just logged that document out without doing anything else with it.

You have several options. If you really just want to add that HTML to the end of the page (for instance, the end of the `body` element), you don't have to explicitly parse the HTML, you could directly append it to the page by doing `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text);` (which will parse it **and** insert it into the document).

Side note: Your code is falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun [I wrote about here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) — be sure to check that the HTTP call succeeded before calling `response.text()`.

So:

```
fetch("https://example.com?page=3")
    .then((res) => {
        if (!res.sok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
        }
        return res.text();
    })
    .then((text) => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text))
    .catch((error) => {
        // ...handle/display error...
    });
```

More: [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

If you want to add it somewhere *other* than the end of `body`, just get the element you want to add it to, and use that instead of `document.body`.

You'll want to make sure the HTML you send back is just content, not a full HTML page with its own `head`, etc.

Alternatively, you could parse it as you have done, then use DOM methods on the returned document to find the content you need from it, and insert those elements into the main page's document via [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement), etc.